# Download a zip file and extract it in memory using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, python-requests

I would like to download a zip file from internet and extract it.

I would rather use requests. I don't want to write to the disk.

I knew how to do that in Python2 but I am clueless for python3.3. Apparently, zipfile.Zipfile wants a file-like object but I don't know how to get that from what requests returns.

If you know how to do it with urllib.request, I would be curious to see how you do it too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

```
request = requests.get(url)
file = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(request.content))
```

What I was missing :

- `request.content` should be used to access the bytes
- `io.BytesIO` is the correct file-like object for `bytes`.

Comment: I agree, my formulation was referring to some kind of black magic :)
Thanks for the precision!

Comment: Hi, is this solution compatible with python 2.7 also ??

Comment: To make it clearer for myself using parts of @aonbyte's answer: `zipDocument = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(request.content))` and then extract/save it: `zipDocument.extractall()`

Answer (score 8):

Here's another approach saving you having to install requests:

```
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(r.read())) as z:
        print( z.namelist() )
```

Comment: I'll give you an upvote so at least it's not < 0, I think it's a good answer, although I prefer using requests :)

Comment: I like this answer - it avoids requiring to install `requests` library for simple use-cases, e.g. downloading asset file from GitHub release.

Answer (score 6):

Using Requests, this can be done very simply.

```
import requests, zipfile, StringIO
response = requests.get(zip_file_url)
zipDocument = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(response.content))
```

Using String.IO you can make a file-like object for the responses content attribute.

If you want to extract to directory you can use the ZipFile's extractall() function

```
zipDocment.extractall()
```

Comment: There is no StringIO.StringIO in Python3. One could use io.StringIO. That fails miserably on my installation. Maybe there is something wrong with my installation :
  TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: -1, this doesn't work in Python 3 - StringIO takes a str while both `ZipFile` and `response.content` require bytes. `io.ByteIO` is the thing to use

Comment: There are typos in the answer and the comment by @dbr: Should be `zipDocument.extractall()` and `io.BytesIO`. I.e., `zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))` (_note: cannot edit the answer_)